# Unable to view Job Messages. 404 error

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, jobs-messages

I'm unable to view My Job Messages. The error is:

***Oh no! We can't find the page you're looking for.***

The same error for all the job messages

Also I see the Easy Apply Button for jobs that I have already applied

[image]

Comment: Are you logged in on Stack Overflow? Or are you trying to access messages related to a job application that you did anonymously?

Comment: Yes I am logged in.

Comment: Now the error is gone and the status is: Loading your message...

Still can not load messages. @AurélienGasser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Initial answer**

You have two accounts on Stack Overflow, registered on emails from different domains.

The messages you're trying to view belong to the other account (not the account you're logged in with). Logging in to the other account, you should be able to access your messages.

**Update**

After further investigation, your two accounts have been merged in the past. So, unlike what I stated above, you only have one Stack Overflow account.

However the merging process didn't complete successfully, leaving your message inbox "orphan" (nobody could access it).

I fixed up your account, you should now be able to see your messages.

Sorry about that, and happy messaging.

Comment: I double checked from both accounts and the same error no matter what email address I use to log in

Comment: @rexhin See my updated answer

Comment: thanks for that. can you. remove the r....a@yahoo.com email address please? I don't have access to that account and I don't want this problem to happen again

Comment: @rexhin You can remove access to your acount by the `@yahoo.com` login on https://stackoverflow.com/users/mylogins/current

Comment: I have this exact same problem for the same reason. I haven't merged two accounts but I have changed my email address in the Stack Overflow settings.